# Stop phonegap app from scrolling when call/hotspot indicator is visible

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

I'm developing an iOS app with phonegap. The UI consists of a number of 'wrappers', laid out horizontally, each at 100% of the height of the viewport.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper-one"></div>
    <div id="wrapper-two"></div>
    <div id="wrapper-three"</div>
  </body>
</body>
```

The `html`, `body` and `#wrapper-*` elements all have `height: 100%` declared in the CSS, which works perfectly, and stops the app from scrolling.

The problem is, that when the 'in call' or 'Personal Hotspot' indicators are visible, they reduce the height of the viewport by around 20px. This then pushes the bottom of the page slightly off screen, and you can scroll up and down. The wrapper divs within the body are scrollable, so I don't want the window to be scrollable as well.

Is there any way that I can stop the scrolling from happening when these indicators are visible, as I have for when only the normal status bar is visible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to detect the window resize and handle it.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    //820 just an example height
    if (window.innerHeight >= 820) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but as far as JS is concerned the window height hasn't changed, it's just moved it down by 20px so that it's slightly off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your MainViewController.m right after MainViewController @implementation and before @end.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) // iOS 7 or above
    {
        CGFloat top = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
        if(self.webView.frame.origin.y == 0){
            // We only want to do this once, or if the view has somehow been "restored" by other code.
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y + top, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height - top);
        }
    }
}
```